# How to setup Geany using windows 7?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, build, compiler-errors

I just learned some C and I want to try it at home. The problem is that whenever I click build, an error like

```
'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

appears below same with the compile button.

Here are the build commands:

- Compile: `gcc -Wall -c "%f"`
- Build: `gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f"`
- Execute: `"./%e"`

Comment: Geany manual recommends [UnxUtils](http://file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Geany/share/doc/geany/html/index.html) instead of MinGW

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to install something like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) to use gcc on Windows.